# uploading zip files with PHP, undefined index

Tags: php, file-upload, zip

I'm having issues uploading zip files and can't seem to find an answer.
Index.php

```
<form id="convertFile" action="convert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input name="upload" type="file" id="inputFile">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

convert.php:

```
if(isset($_FILES)){
    echo $_FILES['upload']['name'];
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'error'));
}
```

When I upload a zip file, I get: Notice: Undefined index: upload in C:\wamp\www\xmlconverter\convert.php on line 3

This is what chrome shows in the post header:

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryuFNy5dZtFj7olmD5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="zip_file"; filename="123.zip"
Content-Type: application/x-zip-compressed


------WebKitFormBoundaryuFNy5dZtFj7olmD5--
```

This works on any other major file format, but can't get it to read the zip file. If I var_dump $_FILES or $_POST they are empty.

What am I missing? Why does all other files work but zip does not.

Thank you

using wamp and php 5.5.12

Answer (score 0):

Where is your zip file type definition?

Anyways, let say this was the html form to upload zip files you'd have the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if($message) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label>Choose a zip file to upload: <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

On the server-side script which handles the post you'd have:

```
<?php
if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
    if(!$continue) {
        $message = "The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file. Please try again.";
    }

    $target_path = "/home/var/yoursite/httpdocs/".$filename;  // change this to the correct site path
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {

        //if you also wanted to extract the file after upload
        //you can do the following

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($target_path);
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo("/home/var/yoursite/httpdocs/"); // change this to the correct site path
            $zip->close();

            unlink($target_path);
        }
        $message = "Your .zip file was uploaded and unpacked.";
    } else {    
        $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Already tried this script. It won't get past the first $_FILE["zip_file"], it throws the same error.

Comment: What do you get when you do print_r($_POST) in your server-side script? Comment everything out and try to see what file items it prints.

Comment: Printing both $_POST and $_FILES returns an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I used a script very similar to one posted by @unixmiah without issue on my cPanel based server. Worked great (and has for year now) but ran into issue of error "PHP, undefined index" when using locally with wamp.

Here is the mod that worked for me:

```
<?php
function rmdir_recursive($dir) {
foreach(scandir($dir) as $file) {
if ('.' === $file || '..' === $file) continue;
if (is_dir("$dir/$file")) rmdir_recursive("$dir/$file");
else unlink("$dir/$file");
}
rmdir($dir);
}
if(!empty($_FILES)){

//added above to script and closing } at bottom

if($_FILES["zip_file"]["name"]) {
    $filename = $_FILES["zip_file"]["name"];
    $source = $_FILES["zip_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $type = $_FILES["zip_file"]["type"];

    $name = explode(".", $filename);
    $accepted_types = array('application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip', 'application/x-compressed');
    foreach($accepted_types as $mime_type) {
        if($mime_type == $type) {
            $okay = true;
            break;
        } 
    }

    $continue = strtolower($name[1]) == 'zip' ? true : false;
    if(!$continue) {
        $message = "<b>The file you are trying to upload is not a .zip file! Please try again...</b>";
    }

    $target_path = "somedir/somesubdir/".$filename;  // change this to the correct site path
    if(move_uploaded_file($source, $target_path)) {
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $x = $zip->open($target_path);
        if ($x === true) {
            $zip->extractTo("somedir/somesubdir/"); // change this to the correct site path
            $zip->close();

            unlink($target_path);
        }
        $message = "<h2>ZIP file was uploaded and content was replaced!</h2>";
    } else {    
        $message = "There was a problem with the upload. Please try again.";
    }
}
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>QikSoft ZIP Upper</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php if(!empty($message)) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">
<label><h3>Upload Your ZIP:</h3> <input type="file" name="zip_file" /></label>
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="START UPLOAD" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also note that the echo message has been changed:

```
<?php if(!empty($message)) echo "<p>$message</p>"; ?>
```

One thing that does not work is file restriction. Currently allows other types besides ZIP. Anyone with fix, be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

It's echo $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];

Comment: 'tmp_name' is for getting it's temporary location. 'name' will echo out the file name. it's a simple test to see if the file is being read correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try checking and adjusting the post_max_size value in your php.ini file, this worked for me as the default is 3M, raised the value to 128M and everything was peachy

Comment: Would have been better as a comment.

Comment: I understand, but i faced a similar issue and that was my solution, sincerest apologies if it was off point to the question, I'm actually new to this, in my own case, I got a blank page with similar "undefined index" error when i tried uploading, after making the adjustment stated i never had the problem with uploading zipfiles again